# Comparing string variables in a makefile

Tags: variables, makefile, string-comparison

I have code that looks like the following (below) where ${IMPJAVASRC:T} evaluates to PJCentric.java.  I would like to compare this string variable to a prefix consisting of just the characters "PJC" since there are other modules with the same prefix which I would like to compile with a different -classpath than other modules that start with a different prefix.  However, my statement below does not evaluate to true.  Any suggestions?

.if !empty(${IMPJAVASRC:T}:MPJC*)
     (compile one way)
.else
     (compile another way)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that you want to use different compilation commands, depending on whether `${IMPJAVASRC:T}` expands to a string beginning with "PJC"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do this if you use specifically **GNU Make** e.g. with its [conditional functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Conditional-Functions.html) or its [control functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Make-Control-Functions.html). But other `make` programs don't give you this ability. However, there also exist **better building programs** than `make` such as [omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html) and Java have also [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)